# CSS Transparent On Hover After CSS Transition

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the button background transparent after the CSS transition on Shopify, but can't seem to do so. Please help.

Here are my CSS codes:

```css
.btn.btn1::before {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 600ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E9E9E9;
}

.btn.btn1:hover::before,
.btn.btn1:focus::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btn.btn1:hover {
  color: gray !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn.btn1:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

Site: https://polished-london.myshopify.com/
Password: home

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you be more specific? after transition on what state? hover? click?

Comment: A link to your site (especially to a page behind a password) isn't an great way to show the problem, once you fix the problem this question will become useless for future readers. As mentioned above, please make sure everything needed to reproduce the issue is in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an animation to the `.btn.btn1:hover::before, .btn.btn1:focus::before` selectors that would cause the background of the `::before` pseudo element to be transparent after the background changes color.  To see where the main change is, you can look in the "IMPORTANT CODE" section.

```css
.btn.btn1::before {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 600ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E9E9E9;
}

/* IMPORTANT CODE */

@keyframes make-transparent {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

.btn.btn1:hover::before,
.btn.btn1:focus::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  /* First number is animation duration, and the second number is the animation delay. */
  /* Adjust them however you'd like. */
  animation: make-transparent 600ms 600ms forwards;
}

/* END IMPORTANT CODE */

.btn.btn1:hover {
  color: gray !important;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn.btn1:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

/* Some of my own styles.  Not important */
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.btn.btn1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* End of personal styles */
```

```html
<a class="btn btn1" href="#">Howdy</a>
```

Comment: That worked! How can I also make the animation transition back from right to left after the unhover?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It seems like it already does that, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I mean that right now the transition effects goes from left to right, and I want to be another transition effect from right to left after the unhover as if the transition effects bounces back like on this website button: https://evolvecs.co.uk/what-we-do/.

Comment: It does.  The only difference is that the button here is slower and has that transparency animation in the middle.

Comment: It actually fades away. See it in my shopify site: https://polished-london.myshopify.com/ pass: home

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well the thing is, the button there is using a whole other set of styles, and I don't know how exactly you applied my code to your website.  If you follow what I have above, the transition should automatically reverse itself when the user stops hovering over the button; that's the default behavior of any CSS pseudo class like hover.

Answer (score -1):

You should exactly specify which button you are referring to.